# python OOP - self.x = y(self.x)

Tags: python, oop

I am new in Python OOP and I try to understand one specific line of code.

This is a part of a code:

```
from random import randrange

class Pet():
    hunger_threshold = 10
    
    def __init__(self, name = "Kitty"):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = randrange(self.hunger_threshold)
```

My question is, what is the different between

```
self.hunger = randrange(self.hunger_threshold) #1)
```

and

```
self.hunger = randrange(hunger_threshold) #2)
```

And why is it valid to to the 2) before doing

```
self.hunger_threshold = hunger_threshold
```

I hope someone can get me understanding.

Comment: #2 should give an error.

Comment: If you're asking what the purpose of `self` is, it's been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-self-parameter-for-methods)

Comment: variable hunger_threshold declared for the class. it will be shared for all instances. to access it you can do self.hunger_threshold or Pet.hunger_thresold. you cant simply access it by hunger_threshold